# How to display a simple custom map with markers in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to display a self made indoor map (a simple jpeg file) in an app and the user should be able to place a marker on this map. The coordinates of the marker should be send to a server (firebase), so that other users can see the marker of other people. Also, the map should be zoomable.

I looked at android map view, but it seems that it's just for google maps and not for self made indoor maps. A simple image view seems also not to be the right way.

Could you guys give me a hint what I should use to display the self made map and how I could manage the markers ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Ground Overlays.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay  
 
[image]

Comment: is it possible to hide the base map after using ground overlay, so that I can only see my self made map ?